# Completion of a stalk not integral domain

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, limits-colimits, formal-completions

We consider the closed subscheme $X:= V(Y^2-X^2(x+1))$ of affine plane $\mathbb{A}^2_k= Spec \text{ } k[X,Y]$. field $k$ is arbitrary. let $x:=(0,0)$ the point representing the prime ideal $(X,Y) \subset k[X,Y]$.

Q: how to prove that the completion $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x}$ of the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ at $x \in X$ is *not* a domain although $X$ itself and $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ are integral.

the motivation for this question comes from a comment in Wedhorn's & Goetz' Algebraic geometry book and motivates the phenomena that the coarseness of Zariski topology often "hides" infinitesimal anomal behavior that violate certain theorems impose local-global principles which hold when we work with Zariski topology.

Back to my question. I'm still not familar with work with inverse limits & it's features. by definition the completion of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ wrt $x=(0,0)$ is

$$\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x}= \varprojlim_{n\in \mathbb {N} }  \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}^n $$

with $\mathfrak{m}:=(y,x)$. by assumption $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is the localization of $k[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^2(x+1))$ at $\mathfrak{m}$.

I see two ways to reach my goal: one is to construct a compatible non zero chain $r:=(a_0,a_1, ..., a_i, ...)$ with $a_i \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}^i$ such that $a_{i+1} +\mathfrak{m}^i=a_i$ and there exist another non zero compatible chain $s:=(b_0,a_1, ..., b_i, ...)$ with $a_j \cdot b_j \in \mathfrak{m}^j$ for every $j \in \mathbb{N}$. this mean that $r,s$ represent two elements in  $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x}$ and are zero divisors.

another idea is just to calculate $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x}$ directly. is it in this case a serious option or too difficult? is there a standard way to calculate completions of local rings with structure $k[X,Y]_{\mathfrak{p}}/(f)$ for $f \in k[X,Y]$ and $\mathfrak{p}$ prime containing f.

Comment: Hey Tim, try to use this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732540/taylor-series-of-sqrt1x-using-sigma-notation to show that the polynomial you are modding out by becomes reducible in completion.

Comment: Hi Alex, yes in the completion I can perform an infinite Taylor expansion and splitting $Y^2-X^2(x+1) $ into two non unit factors would give me the desired zero divisors. that's great, thank you. one side note: to calculate concretely the completion of the stalk directly is in this case hopeless or also realistic? the structure of my stalk is $k[X,Y]_{\mathfrak{p}}/(f)$ and my hope was that maybe completions commute with the quotients implying $\widehat{(k[X,Y]_{\mathfrak{p}}/(f))}\cong  (\widehat{k[X,Y]_{\mathfrak{p}}})/(f)$. or is this ansatz wrong?

Comment: Yes, completion commutes with quotients. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: yes it was. so at least we have $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x}= (\widehat{k[X,Y]_{\mathfrak{p}}})/(F)$ with $F=Y^2-X^2(X+1)$. but the completion not commutes with localizations therefore $\widehat{k[X,Y]_{\mathfrak{p}}}$ cannot be simplified more?

Comment: Note that if $A$ is a ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ then $A/\mathfrak{m}^i$ is the same as $A_\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^i$ so localization doesn't make a big difference. The completion is just $k[[x,y]]$ in your case.

Comment: the aspect that confuses me is the following: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191725/completion-of-a-local-ring-of-a-curve if we have a projective variety $A :=V(F_1,...,F_m) \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ described by polynomials $F_i$ then at it's regular points $a \in Reg(A)$ which fullfil the Cohen structure theorem condition the completions have structure $k[[X_1,...,X_d]]$, $d=dim(A)$. on the other hand the completions at non regular stalks seem to be non easy to calculate. but using the rules and especially the compatibility of completions with quotients and localisations

Comment: the completion of the stalk $O_{X,x}$ at an arbitrary not neccessary regular point $x \in X$ seems to be not so difficult: assume $x \in X \cap D_+(X_0) \subset D_+(X_0) \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ lies in the $X_0$-chart. $D_+(X_0)\cong \mathbb{A}^{n-1}$ is regular and $X$ is zero locus of the polynomials $F_i$. therefore $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x} = k[[X_1,...,X_n]]/(f_1,...,f_m)$ with $f_i =F(1,X_1,...,X_n)$ by usage of the commutativity of completions with quotients and regularity of affine space. on the other hand  I'm not sure if the structure of the completions $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x}$

Comment: of stalks at arbitrary points of arbitrary projective maybe non smooth schemes are really relatively of such nice shape $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x} = k[[X_1,...,X_n]]/(f_1,...,f_m)$. do I miss some point?