# What is the series expansion for the solution of x given the speacial case x^2 + px - p = 0?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was solving a chemistry problem on the chemistry section of Stackexchange and I need a little help. The underlying problem is to reduce [equation (8)](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/133107/22102) to some sort of series expansion.

I've basically ended with with a reduced quadratic equation of the form:

$$x^2 + p\cdot x -p = 0\tag{1}$$

Due to the nature of the chemistry problem x is constrained by $ 0 < x <=1$. So instead of two roots due to + and - of the square term, only the + sqrt will work. Thus using the quadratic equation solution:

$$ x = -\dfrac{p}{2} + \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{p}{2}\right)^2 + p}\tag{2} $$

Now for small $p$ the approximate solution is $x \approx \sqrt{p}$. This is chemistry not "real" math so 2 or 3 significant figures is plenty. ;-)

Rearranging equation (2) I can get:

$$x = \sqrt{p}\cdot \left(\sqrt{\dfrac{p}{4} + 1} - \sqrt{\dfrac{p}{4}} \right)\tag{3}$$

This fairly quickly approaches

$$x = \sqrt{p}\cdot \left(1 - \dfrac{p^{1/2}}{2} + \dfrac{p}{8} + ??\right)\tag{4}$$

So I strongly suspect some sort of series expansion exists.

**What is the series expansion for equation (4)?**

I know that $\sqrt{\dfrac{p}{4} + 1}$ has a [series expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732540/taylor-series-of-sqrt1x-using-sigma-notation) but I can figure out what to do with the term $\sqrt{\dfrac{p}{4}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you face expression such as $$x = \sqrt{p}\, \left(\sqrt{\dfrac{p}{4} + 1} - \sqrt{\dfrac{p}{4}} \right)$$ and you suspect that $p$ could be very small, you must be cautious because if $p < 4 \epsilon$ ($\epsilon$ being the machine accuracy), the first radical would be $1$ making the result to be wrong.

So, in a first step, rewrite
 $$x = \sqrt{p}\, \left(\sqrt{\dfrac{p}{4} + 1} - \sqrt{\dfrac{p}{4}} \right)\frac{\sqrt{\dfrac{p}{4} + 1} + \sqrt{\dfrac{p}{4}} } {\sqrt{\dfrac{p}{4} + 1} +\sqrt{\dfrac{p}{4}} }=\frac {\sqrt{p}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{p}{4} + 1} +\sqrt{\dfrac{p}{4}} }$$ which would be safer.

Now, for an *approximation*, you could use the Taylor series of the denominator
$${\sqrt{\dfrac{p}{4} + 1} +\sqrt{\dfrac{p}{4}} }=1+\frac{\sqrt{p}}{2}+\frac{p}{8}+O\left(p^{2}\right)$$ which makes
$$x \sim \frac {\sqrt{p}}{1+\frac{\sqrt{p}}{2}+\frac{p}{8}}$$

For $p=1$ (a large value), the exact result is $x=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\approx 0.618$ while the approximation would give $x \sim \frac{8}{13}\approx 0.615$.

Comment: **First - Thanks for the heavy lifting!** // In the chemistry problem I working with p would never get so small that $p < 4 \epsilon$, but is it really nice to have all the series terms be positive. That way the approximate expression is obviously larger than the true value from the quadratic.

Comment: @MaxW. Think about problems wih ion concentrations. By the way, you are very welcome ! Cheers.

Comment: Claude - Yes, approximations are used extensively in chemistry. For calculations in aqueous solutions two or three significant figures is almost always enough. Also I don't remember a word problems in a chemistry book that required more than a quadratic equation when the appropriate assumptions were made. // I'm an old goat. I solved problems for years with 4 place logs or a slide rule. ;-)

Comment: @MaxW. Guess what ? 62+ years ago I grduated as a  chemist (physical aspects). I still use my slide rules. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Write:

$\begin{align*}
  x 
    &= - \frac{p}{2} + \sqrt{p + \frac{p^2}{4}} \\
    &= - \frac{p}{2} + \sqrt{p} \cdot \sqrt{1 + \frac{p}{4}} \\
    &= - \frac{p}{2} 
           + \sqrt{p}
               \cdot \left(
                        1
                          + \frac{1}{2} \frac{p}{4}
                          - \frac{1}{8} \left(\frac{p}{4}\right)^2
                          + \dotsb
                     \right)
\end{align*}$

Written this way as $p^2 / 4$ is much less than $p$ (as you are interested in small $p$).

The last by the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), which states here for $\lvert x \rvert < 1$:

$\begin{align*}
   (1 + x)^{1/2}
     &= 1
          + \sum_{n \ge 1}
              \frac{(-1)^{n - 1}}{n 2^{2 n - 1}}
                \, \binom{2 n - 2}{n - 1} x^n 
\end{align*}$