# What is the sum of the series $\sum_0^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n-3)!!x^{n}}{(2n)!!}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to find the sum of the series $\sum_0^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n-3)!!x^{n}}{(2n)!!}$ and for that I can calculate the limit of the given sum as $n$ approaches infinity. However, I have no idea where to start. I know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(-1)^{n-1}$ does not exist, because the expression oscillates between $+1$ and $-1$. Shouldn't it follow from this that  $\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}\sum_0^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n-3)!!x^{n}}{(2n)!!}$ also doesn't exist?

If my line of attack is doomed, is there any other way to find the sum of the series, i.e. without calculating the limit?

NOTE: The double factorial means $k!!=(1)(3)(5)...(k)$ if $k$ is odd and $k!!=(2)(4)(6)...(k)$ if $k$ is even.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732540/taylor-series-of-sqrt1x-using-sigma-notation